# vlookup in Sharepoint 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have 2 sharepoint lists in Sharepoint 2010 environment. Sharepoint A list and Sharepoint B list. Sharepoint A list has multiple columns including 2 columns .i.e. Country and Region. there are multiple users who enter data into this sharepoint A list and they populate the values in all columns including Country and Region, the ask is that if they populate the country in the Country column then the Region should automatically get populated by looking up the value of Region form Sharepoint List B which consists of only 2 columns .i.e. Country and Region and it has an exhaustive list of countries and the region mapped against it. Can someone please advise how can I achieve this without making any server level changes or installations.

Comment: Vlookup is a feature of excel , i dont think there is any way to apply any formula on list in sharepoint, it may be done via coding

Answer (score 1):

Without using vlookup, this can be achieved in javascript using `$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns`. There is a good country and region example at http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/value-added/SPCascadeDropdowns.html.

Here is the sample code for country and region lists. This code can be used in a content editor webpart on NewForm or EditForm pages where Country and Region dropdowns exist.

```
<!-- Modify the src paths as required -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jQuery%20Libraries/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jQuery%20Libraries/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "ListB",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Region",
    parentColumn: "Country",
    childColumn: "Region",
    debug: true
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Will this work with sharepoint 2010 list with no server level changes ?

Comment: Also I have got 2 lists one is Source List/Mapping List which has both Country and Region columns next to each other and another one is Target List in which the country is a Text field (since users want it like that) and region is a lookup column which has a dropdown showing regions from the Mapping List region column, user requirement is that if they enter the country name in the country text field of target list then the region should automatically get populated based on the mapping field mapping for the entered country.

Comment: You can achieve this by binding a change event on country textbox. Check text length in the change event. If it is lets say > 3 then call sharepoint rest api via ajax to get the region

Comment: can you share an example or screenshot since I am not clear on this.

Comment: Sorry @adifadipe, its a bit complex and requires a considerable amount of time to write that code. I would suggest you to go for the solution that is in my answer. You only need to create two choice columns Country and Region. The javascript will load the countries in the country choice field. Once you select any country, it would load the relevant regions from the source list. You may be able to type in the country field for quick selection.